# How to activate a php extension on a 1and1 shared server?

Tags: php, sockets

I just created a web application that uses sockets in my local server. Everything works.
The problems start when I hosted my resources on a 1and1 shared server. I get the following fatal error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function socket_create ()

it is clear that the extension php_socket is not enabled.
There's there a way to enable this extension by code?

Comment: With shared hosting the answer is almost always `No`

Comment: Some shared hosts permit per-account php.ini files - see if yours provides this. It'll be in the online help, I should think.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it would be best directed to the technical support pages/department of a third party.

Comment: @halfer I already redirect this question to the technical support of 1and1 but unfortunately I get nothing until now. I relied on the generosity of stackoverflow community.

Comment: @Ichamoovi - you seem to have forgotten to mention what the technical support people actually said to you? `;-)`

Comment: @halfer -- I'm still waiting but without much hope of good news.

Comment: Errrr..... is [this any good](http://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/linux-c85098/php-c37728/change-php-directives-a660257.html)?

Comment: @halfer-- no, not for my case. with *.htacces* we can only change some basic parameters such as the maximum size of a file download. but we can't act directly on important extensions. I think the solution is to have a dedicated server that we can freely configure.

Comment: @Ichamoovi: read the bit that says "Editing the php.ini file". It _may_ not apply in your case, but I suspect it actually does. This document applies to "Linux Web Hosting" as well as "Managed Servers", either of which are "running PHP as a CGI".

Comment: @halfer I have read.
I overload the *php.ini* file setting inside **extension=php_sockets.dll**. the same error occurs

Comment: Ahem, a DLL (a Windows extension) on a Linux server? Try `php_sockets.so`. Again, you need to await an answer from technical support about this, I think.

Comment: @halfer __ corrected and it gives nothing.
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases, you **cannot** install or activate additional PHP modules on shared hosting.

Shared hosting has a very limited perimeter and strict security requirements. Most functions for program execution and networking will be disabled on most shared hosting offers. Shared hosting offers that let you do anything are very rare and priced accordingly.

Besides, installing or activating extensions at execution time is impossible since PHP version 5.3. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php

If you want to build advanced applications, shared hosting is not the right product choice. Look for virtual servers (which you can set up as you like) or even get a full dedicated server.

---

If you really want to press the matter, I recommend contacting your 1&1 customer service and ask for directions there. They may or may not be able to help you on to achieve your goal.